# Simple AJAX Retrieval of data in XML file, going wrong around ".responseXML"

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

I've searched and searched and quadruple checked spelling and syntax and I'm stumped.  I even checked the syntax on "jslint".  I've placed all the code on "jsfiddle":

http://jsfiddle.net/sxtuX/

```
var xmlHttp= createXmlHttpRequestObject();

function createXmlHttpRequestObject(){
   var xmlHttp;
   if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
      xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else{
      xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   return xmlHttp;
}

function process() {
   if (xmlHttp) {
      try{
         xmlHttp.open("GET", "data_people.xml", true);
         xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange;
         xmlHttp.send(null);
      } 
      catch (e) {
        alert ("In process function.<br/>Error in creating xmlHttp object: "+ e.toString());
      }
   }
}

function handleStateChange() {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4) {
       if (xmlHttp.status==200) {
          try {
             handleResponse();
          }
          catch(e) {
             alert ("Trouble getting text." + e.toString());
          }         
        }
        else {
           alert ("State = "+xmlHttp.readyState+" Status= " + xmlHttp.status);
        }
    }
}

function handleResponse() {
    var xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML,
        root = xmlResponse.documentElement,
        names = root.getElementsByTagName("name"),
        ssns = root.getElementsByTagName("ssn");

    alert (xmlHttp.responseText);

    var stuff = "";
    for(var i=0;i<names.length;i++) {
        stuff = names.item(i).firstChild.data + "-" + ssns.item(i).firstChild.data + "<br/>";
    }
    theD = document.getElementById("theD");
    theD.innerHTML = stuff;
}
```

The javascript works fine up until the last function "handleResponse()" which is the last function.  I've placed an "alert" after all the variable declarations using "xmlHttp.responseText" just to prove to myself the file is being accessed and it does print the entire XML file in the alert window.

I tried to create the XML datafile on "jsfiddle" by following the instructions, assuming it was like the HTML file example, but I couldn't get it to work.

So my questions: Why isn't "xmlHttp.responseXML" returning anything?  It's either that or something is going wrong with .documentElement. When I examine "names.length" or "ssns.length" they are both zero.  Also, can I get some assistance in figuring out the proper way to code an XML file on "jdfiddle" by correcting my fibble attempt?

Comment: Your fiddle is bad JavaScript.  Quotations marks in XML are not escaped.  Open browser console to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have your javascript options in the fiddle are set up it only gets executed `onLoad` (which means all your functions will be defined inside an onload function - and will both not be available in the global scope nor before said function has been executed). It's a catch 22 with sprinkles on top. You'll need to set the second dropdown on the left to either `No wrap - in <head>` or `No wrap - in <body>`.

Next up - the jsfiddle example code. There's a whole bunch wrong here:

1. You should have been referencing Request - not Request.XML (which you just made up ;P). And you should have included the MooTools library (first dropdown on the left) - because that's where Request is from ;)
2. The url is case sensitive! `"/echo/xml/"` instead of `"/echo/XML/"`.
3. The xml string needs to be have properly escaped quotes and javascript strings don't support raw line-breaks (they can be escaped too... but that's another story) - just collapse them for now.

... But you don't need that example. Just use your own code!

Just remember to use the proper test url (with `POST` not `GET`) and escape/collapse your test xml.

This is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sxtuX/3/

Comment: None of what you are saying was anywhere I could find on "jsfiddle" or in any of my internet search efforts.  I suspected I was somehow supposed to integrate the POST and filename in the "process" function.  Your example certainly clears it all up.  Thanks so much for a very clear example.

So that definitely solves the issue of getting my code to the point of working on "jsfiddle" exactly like it does on my computer.  Now I'm back to my primary question...why isn't the code working to extract the <name> and <ssn> data to provide a list of names in the handleResponse() function?

Comment: The final bit is that the xml header has whitespace that needs to be removed: `<? xml` -> `<?xml`

Comment: That is incredible embarrassing.  That was the same thing that happened to the person giving the tutorial and I forgot to go back and correct it.  Amazing how one little space can totally break the code.  I can give this a check mark, but I don't have enough reputation yet to give an up tick.  Thanks so much "rasmusfl0e".